# .NET Base type information?

Tags: .net

Is there any convenient function to get a list of base types of a class. For example, I want to get base types (both interfaces and classes) of ArrayList class. The result should include "Object, IList, ICollection, IEnumerable, and ICloneable"

Please advise.

Comment: I know it's just an example, but don't use ArrayList

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can only ever be one base class, no MI in .NET, Type.BaseType.  There can be many interfaces, Type.GetInterfaces().  Gluing them together in your preferred format is up to you.

Answer (score 3):

It's not exactly what you're looking for, but in addition to Hans' answer the [Type.IsAssignableFrom()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx) method might help you.